# GeoIP gem with Rails undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, geoip

I am using GeoIP gem to get the longtitude and latitude of an ip in Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0, but in the console.log line, there is an error.

undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass

```
<% @all.each do |item| %>
    <% @geo = GeoIP.new("#{Rails.root}/public/GeoLiteCity.dat").city(item.ip) %>
    console.log("<%= @geo.latitude  %>");
    var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("<%= @geo.latitude %>", "<%= @geo.longitude %>");
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatlng,
    title: "<%= item.referer %>",
    draggable: false,
    map: map
    });

  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a GeoIP bug when you use Rails 4